# What is AngularDart? How is it different from Angular 2+? Why is nobody talking about it? Is it good or bad?

Tags: angular, typescript, dart, angular-dart

I am personally a fan of Dart. I like dart because it's awesome.
I wanted to start working Angular2+ then I came across AngularDart. But I found almost nothing on how it's different for Angular 2+ .
Which one should I start working on and why? 
Can any help with to understand this?

Comment: Did you check the [angular-dart tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-dart/info)?

Comment: Checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txEqvqKzISY)

Comment: Opinion-based questions are likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Thank you all, that explains it...

Answer (score 3):

as name might imply, it is angular but written in dart, AngularDart started out with the same codebase as the TypeScript Angular framework, which is documented at angular.io.
Although the code is now separate, the two projects are as similar as possible, while still making the most of Dart features and libraries. In other words, the underline architecture are similar for both Angular and AngularDart. google try to push developer to use dart, even though google mentioned that they believe that developers should have a choice when they build for the web. Adding a new option, such as Dart, does not imply replacing an existing option. finally,AngularDart has most of features angular have, but it is not up to date as Angular Typescript, AngularDart5 shipped as part of Dart2. if you used angular typescript before, you will find AngularDart similar. take a look https://webdev.dartlang.org/faq and https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-stable-and-the-dart-web-platform-3775d5f8eac7 for more details about future of AngularDart